# phpmailer alter header of email

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

i have a website hosted on Lamp server, there is a contact form will send email from a smtp (gmail) using phpmailer,

i add a custom hostname in phpmailer script

```
  public $Hostname          = 'www.google.com';

  /**
   * Sets the message ID to be used in the Message-Id header.
   * If empty, a unique id will be generated.
   * @var string
   */
```

when i view the source of the email there is a line in header

```
Received: from www.google.com (234092384281.ctinets.com. [server.ip.ip.ip])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPSA id ve6sm3340494pbc.21.2013.05.29.21.17.15
        for <mygmailacc@gmail.com>
        (version=TLSv1 cipher=RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
        Wed, 29 May 2013 21:17:16 -0700 (PDT)
```

is it possible to remove the (234092384281.ctinets.com. [server.ip.ip.ip]) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible when you are using Google SMTP, they control it then. Not you. If you have to get rid of that then you will have to use your own SMTP server